# bootstrap input validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using the bootstrap input validation classes and jquery, is there a better way to validate the input immediately after user entered something than this:

```
CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL.blur(function(event) {
    if (CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL.is(':valid')) {
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_CONTAINER.addClass('has-success has-feedback');
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_GLYPHICON.addClass('glyphicon-ok');

        // if previous input was invalid
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_GLYPHICON.removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_CONTAINER.removeClass('has-error');
    }
    else {
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_CONTAINER.addClass('has-error has-feedback');
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_GLYPHICON.addClass('glyphicon-remove');

        // if previous input was valid
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_GLYPHICON.removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_CONTAINER.removeClass('has-success');
    }
    CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_GLYPHICON.removeClass('invisible');
});

CONTACT_MODAL.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_CONTAINER.removeClass('has-feedback has-success has-error');
    CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL.val('');
    CONTACT_INPUT_EMAIL_GLYPHICON.addClass('invisible');
});
```

All this code is just for a single email input and seems very cumbersome to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin such as http://formvalidation.io/

This can help reduce the cumbersome code to something simpler.